# install mysqlworkbench 6.3.7 CE edition on window 10 pro error

Tags: windows-10, mysql-workbench

I install mysqlworkbench 6.3.7 community version and got this error
"
THE PROGRAM CAN'T START BECAUSE MSVCR120.DLL IS MISSING FORM YOUR COMPUTER. TRY REINSTALLING THE PROGRAM TO FIX THE PROBLEM.
"

Answer (score 0):

It did not work with the above error was because i used wins x86 version , so I downloaded wins x86, 64-bit version and it works. that is all. tested.